# how to prepare a good JSON file - django

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

Hope you are doing well ! I don't know how to make a good queryset in my **views.py** here

this is my **models.py**

```
class Evenement(models.Model):
    EVENEMENT_CHOICES = (
        ("déposé","déposé"),
        ("reçu","reçu"),
        ("expédié","expédié"),
        ("affecté","affecté"),
        ("livré","livré"),
        ("echec de livraison","echec de livraison"),
    )
    mail_item_fid = models.ForeignKey(mail_item,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mail_item_fid_evenement')
    from_office = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Evt_evenement')
    date_Evt = models.DateField() 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=EVENEMENT_CHOICES)
    agent_delivery_cd = models.ForeignKey(Delivery_Agent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True ,related_name='agent_evenement')
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}, {} '.format(self.mail_item_fid,self.from_office,self.date_Evt,self.status)
```

I want a json file like below :

```
Date : 15/06/2020
from_post : X
affecte : 100
J+0 : 50
J+1 : 25
J+2 : 25

Date : 15/06/2020
from_post : Y
affecte : 1000
J+0 : 400
J+1 : 250

Date : 15/06/2020
from_post : Z
affecte : 150
J+0 : 25
J+1 : 50

Date : 16/06/2020
from_post : X
affecte : 1000
J+0 : 500
J+1 : 250
J+2 : 25

Date : 16/06/2020
from_post : Y
affecte : 1050
J+0 : 400
J+1 : 250

Date : 16/06/2020
from_post : Z
affecte : 1000
J+0 : 25
J+1 : 50
```

I should do the day difference between two status 'affecte' and 'livre' , to show wether the delivery agents delivered items in the same day it is 'affecté' or in another day J+0 or J+1 (J means Day)and so on , I don't know what should I put in my queryset

Comment: You want to get a date range from the model?

Comment: I think for date range in the queryset I have to put something like `Evenement.objects.annotate(Day=TruncDay('date_Evt')).values('Day'` but I don't know about other things

Comment: I don't know how to make it right , please if you have any advice write it in answer

Comment: I just have no idea exactly what you are trying to get. You are asking what to put in your Query set but what did you want to return?

Comment: I want to return a json file like I wrote above , in a specific date I want to get the Count of  mail_items 'status=affecte' and then the total of mail_items delivered 'status=livré' `testing = Evenement.objects.annotate(Day=TruncDay('date_Evt')).values('Day','from_office__office_NM')\
        .annotate( dateAffecte = Count('mail_item_fid',filter=Q(status='affecté')),
                   dateLivre = Count('mail_item_fid',filter=Q(status='livré'))
        ).all().order_by('Day')` I was trying this queryset but I don't know how to continue this ...

Comment: the queryset I wrote it return only delivered mail_items in the same date , my goal is to count how many mails delivered in day+0 and day+1 etc ...

Comment: ```attendance_records = attendance_records.filter(incident_date__gte=start_date, incident_date__lte=end_date)``` This is how you do date ranges. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I don't know how to use it here ... but thanks for your help